# how to make POST action from another server - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rest, security

How can i make post request from another server to my laravel server?

I have a website from another provider (lets say domainA.com) , they have CMS system, so I can make my custom pages - the question is, I want to make a form in domainA.com, and post it to domainB.com (my original Server), how can I make it in laravel? As far as I understand I should use api route file for this, is it secure to make such a POST request? because as far as I understand there is no token protection on api requests right?

sorry for my english - i am most interested in security side of such a action - if you show me an example, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.4 has 2 route groups: `web` and `api`

the web group is used for all requests that come from the current laravel application. Laravel uses a csrf token with every request to make sure every request is coming from the own page to prevent cross site scripting.

the api group is for requests that a fired from an external server. For this group the csrf protection is disabled.

Remember: csrf protection **ONLY** checks if the requests is from your site, it does **not** handle the authentication or authorization.

To secure your API you can use json web tokens (jwt). There is a [package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) that will handle the authentication parts for APIs.

If you want to keep it really simple you can write a middleware for all api calls, that is checking if the requests has a special value (your personal token) to give access to the api.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to accept post request to a Laravel Route and you can define route any of web.php or api.php route file but below are the differences.

web.php

Routes in Web.php will prevent the form without CSRF Token.
to avoid that you can add the route in **VerifyCsrfToken.php** file in except Array.

api.php

Routes will work directly but the api URL will be `Example.com/api/<route>`.

But for security you can share an Access Token for the routes and in the controller you can verify the requests with the access token and allow post.

Answer (score 0):

You are right is not sure about this communication.

What you can do is a chain token code

Start with a code and every time you contact the server b it will give you a new code that you will need to use for the next message.

I know it's not as beautiful as a solution but I do not think of anything else.

You could implement your api framework but you would spend a lot of time